# ServiceStack.Text how to serialize class to JSon

Tags: c#, json, servicestack

Just downloaded ServiceStack.Text to use it in my ASP.NET. I have class with many properties and would like to serialize five of them(string, integer, binary) to JSON. Could anyone post simple example how to create JSon object from my class?

Comment: Import to note that though you need `using ServiceStack;` in your imports, the `ToJson` method requires not only a ref to ServiceStack but also requires a reference to ServiceStack.Text in your project.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ServiceStack will deserialize all public properties of a POCO by default.

If you only want to serialize just a few of the properties then you want to decorate your class with [DataContract], [DataMember] attributes (in the same way you would if you were using MS DataContractJsonSerializer), e.g:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
    public string WillNotSerializeString { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string WillSerializeString { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int WillSerializeInt { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public byte[] WillSerializeByteArray { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use either the static utility methods on JsonSerializer to (De)serialize it, or the more terse extension methods, e.g:

```
var dto = new MyClass { WillSerializeString = "some text" };
string json = dto.ToJson();
MyClass fromJson = json.FromJson<MyClass>();
```

Edit:

As @Noah mentions (from comments) you can also use the [IgnoreDataMember] attribute to exclude a single property.

Comment: Similarly, if you want all of your properties serialized _except_ one, you can decorate just that property with `[IgnoreDataMember]`, BUT you should NOT decorate the class with `[DataContract]` in that case, or it will not work as expected.  I just did this with ServiceStack on a project, and was happy to see that it worked.

Comment: And note: serialize/deserialize all public >properties<, that does NOT include >fields<.

Comment: @Quandary Right, you need to set `JsConfig.IncludePublicFields = true;` to serialize public fields, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15372520/85785

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `[Serializable()]` attribute on your custom class and then:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

var Json = serializer.Serialize(myObject);
```

To ignore specific properties in the object you're serializing, simply place the `[NonSerialized]` attribure on them.

**Update:**

Given that you want to use ServiceStack to do your serialization, the ServiceStack website gives the following example:

```
var customer = new Customer { Name="Joe Bloggs", Age=31 };
var json = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(customer);
var fromJson = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Customer>(json);
```

Source: http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344

Comment: I don't want to use Microsoft serializer because it is very slow. I ask about  ServiceStack.Text

Comment: If you're specifically interested in ServiceStack.Text then what's stopping you from downloading their sample project and just having a look?

Comment: The ServiceStack website even shows you how to use it: http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344

Comment: I have already searched their web site and found example which you refer. I don't want to serialize the whole class, I want to select which properties to serialize and build my own JSon object with ServiceStack.Text.

Answer (score 1):

servicestack's test proves that by providing the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attribute allows you to determine which one is being serialized and which doesn't.

Test: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/DataContractTests.cs

objects in test: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/Support/DdnDtos.cs