# Adding the object name to its serialized string

Tags: c#, json.net

Let's say I have this object:

```
[JsonObject]
public class User
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "birthday")]
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

This will produce JSON like this:

```
{
   "id":null,
   "name":"Bob",
   "birthday":"/Date(374479200000-0600)/"
}
```

I'm looking for a way to add the classname around all this, for example:

```
{
   "user":{
      "id":null,
      "name":"Bob",
      "birthday":"/Date(374479200000-0600)/"
   }
}
```

Does JSON.NET have a way to do this? Thanks!

**Edit**

My reason for doing this was to connect a .NET client to a Rails web service. Rails puts a model's attributes under a namespace, so I was looking for a way for .NET to conform to this.

However, after reading a bit about [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/), it looks like a possible  alternative would be to disable this behavior in Rails:

> If you're working with a Rails backend, you'll notice that Rails'
>   default to_json implementation includes a model's attributes under a
>   namespace. To disable this behavior for seamless Backbone integration,
>   set:
>
> ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false

Comment: sounds like you need DataContractJsonSerializer.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx

Comment: @DJKRAZE: I appreciate your response, but can you please point me to an example usage that accomplishes my goal? Thanks!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307100/servicestack-text-how-to-serialize-class-to-json

Comment: @DJKRAZE: I appreciate the links but they don't really show that the resulting JSON has the class name wrapped around the POCO properties. I know I could just try it, but your suggestion would be much more helpful with an example that actually demonstrates my goal being achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this just for the root object, I think the simplest way is just to enclose the object in a way that it gets serialized the way you want:

```
static object AddTypeName(object o)
{
    return new Dictionary<string, object> 
    {
        { o.GetType().Name.ToLowerInvariant(), o }
    };
}
```

Comment: This seems like a very clean way to do it from the .NET side. It turns out, the question I should've been asking is how to REMOVE the namespace on the Rails side. I've edited my question to show that solution. Thanks for your tip!

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this personally using [JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292287.aspx):

```
JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavascriptSerializer();
javaScriptSerializer.Serialize( new { user = userObject } );
```

That should automatically deserialize the following class:

```
class User 
{ 
    string id;
    int age;
}
```

into this:

```
{
    user : {
        id = '12321345',
        age = 32
    }
}
```