# How to Deserialize data from file to Custom Class with ServiceStack.Text JsonSerializer?

Tags: c#, json, servicestack

I have student class with following structure:

```
    public class Student
    {
       public int StudentId {get;set;}
       public string StudentName {get;set;}
       public string[] Courses {get;set;}
    }
```

I have a student.json file which saves the data of Student class as below:

```
    public void SaveStudentData(Student stud, string path)   //stud is an object of student class that has student information
    {
        string studinfo = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString<Student>(stud);
        StreamWriter sw = File.OpenText(path);
        sw.Write(studinfo);

    }
```

But, when I try to retrieve the data using the following code:

```
    public Student GetStudentData(string path)
    {
       StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path);
       string stud = sr.ReadToEnd();
       sr.Close();
       Student studinfo =JsonSerializer.SerializeToString<Student>(stud);
       return studinfo;

    }
```

The line

```
   Student studinfo =JsonSerializer.SerializeToString<Student>(stud);
```

is highlighted by VS 2012 saying that it cannot convert String type to Student type.I want to convert the json data from file to Student class. How should I do it?

Comment: See the method name **`SerializeToString`**. It returns a string. There should be a method like `DeserializeFromString`

Comment: Have a look at this so answer: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7314819/937411

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After [looking here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text)

I'd suggest you'd have much more luck deserializing by calling the

```
T JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<T>(string value)
```

method, rather than the `SerializeToString<T>` which is the inverse of what you want. So non generically,

```
Student studinfo = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Student>(stud);
```

---

Since you are `using` the `ServiceStack.Text` assembly you could just use the `T.ToJson()` or `string.FromJson<T>()` extensions, as commented by @mythz.

Comment: Note: TypeSerializer is for the [JSV Format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/wiki/JSV-Format). What you want is `JsonSerializer` or the `T.ToJson()` or `string.FromJson<T>()` extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `SerializeToString` which from your earlier code returns a `string` type.  Perhaps you should try a method that will return the `Student` object.

I am not familiar with the library you are using.  You can use the `DataContractJsonSerializer` to serialize and deserialze an object like so.

```
    public void Save(Student student, string path)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Student));
        ser.WriteObject(fs, student);
        fs.Close();
    }

    public Student Load(string path)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Student));
        Student s = (Student)ser.ReadObject(fs);
        fs.Close();
        return s;
    }
```

Where the student object is decorated as such

```
[DataContract]
public class Student
{
    [DataMember]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string[] Courses { get; set; }
}
```