# JSON parsing object to string - preserve order of elements

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have this class that needs to be serialized to json:

```
[DataContract]
public class InfoRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public string folder_id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string file_type_id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string prefix { get; set; }

    [DataMember] 
    public fileInfo[] files;

    [DataMember] 
    public termInfo[] terms;
}

[DataContract]
public class fileInfo
{
    [DataMember] 
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember] 
    public string size { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class termInfo
{
    [DataMember] 
    public string term_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember] 
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried ServiceStack.Text, NewtonSoft.Json, and DataContractJsonSerializer.  I get different results from each library, and none of them preserve the order of the DataMembers.  (ServiceStack doesn't even serialize all the DataMembers.)
Passing the same InfoRequest object to each library, I get these strings:
 JsonConvert:

```
{
   "files":[
      {
         "name":"Blip.txt",
         "size":"448"
      },
      {
         "name":"blip.jpg",
         "size":"71535"
      }
   ],
   "terms":[
      {
         "term_id":"1000",
         "value":"Copyright"
      },
      {
         "term_id":"1000",
         "value":"Copyright"
      }
   ],
   "folder_id":"11245",
   "file_type_id":"234",
   "prefix":"",
   "ServiceStack":{
      "folder_id":"11245",
      "file_type_id":"234",
      "prefix":""
   },
   "MS":{
      "file_type_id":"234",
      "files":[
         {
            "name":"Blip.txt",
            "size":"448"
         },
         {
            "name":"blip.jpg",
            "size":"71535"
         }
      ],
      "folder_id":"11245",
      "prefix":"",
      "terms":[
         {
            "term_id":"1000",
            "value":"Copyright"
         },
         {
            "term_id":"1000",
            "value":"Copyright"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I suspect the order of DataMembers should *not* matter, but I'm getting an error from the server, and think that this might be the issue.
Any insight would be appreciated...

Comment: what error are you getting from server. because yes,order of data member doesn't matter generally.since when you deserialize it, it automatically convert into that object

Comment: I really doubt the order matters (unless you're dealing with a really funky server application), so you may want to test that theory before spending too much time dealing with the order. Try manually posting your JSON once the way the app is currently serializing, then rearrange the string the way you want it to look, and post again. This will tell you if the error is related to the order of the parameters.

Comment: I don't see you set Order property of your DataMembers. How about a try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.order.aspx?

Comment: JSON doesn't really have any inherent ordering of members.  It is case sensitive though... or at least the JavaScript object it preserves case in the property names.  Are you certain your properties are in the correct case?

Answer (score 0):

Note [ServiceStack's JSON Serializer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) only serializers **public properties** by default, if you want to include public fields as well (e.g. so it serializers 'files' and 'terms' as well) you need to include:

```
ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.IncludePublicFields = true;
```

[DataMembers does affect serialization in ServiceStack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14859968/85785) which makes all fields opt-in, use `IgnoreDataMember` if you want to opt-out.