# Bind items in generic list and Serialize

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json.net, generic-list

**This is my code:**

```
List<Test> list = new List<Test>();
for (int j = 0; j < dss.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
{
    list.Add(new Test(dss.Tables[0].Rows[j]["PSet"].ToString(), 
                      Convert.ToInt32(dss.Tables[0].Rows[j]["Score"].ToString())));
}
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
json.Serialize(list, data);
hdlineData.Value = list.ToString();
```

But it's not serializing my list, if i am not binding list correctly. Please suggest me how to bind list in Json format.

Comment: When you say that it doesn't serialise your list, what do you mean? What happens when you run the code, and how does that differ from what you expect? Do you get any error message?

Comment: not giving any error but showing result like - {},{},{},{}. i mean its blank

Comment: i bind one more list and that is works find but in that list only 2 items there, and in this list bind from DataSet, here is code for list.

Comment: List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>{new Task{TaskType="Correct",HoursPerDay=10},new Task{TaskType="Attampted",HoursPerDay=20},
                                    };

                                StringBuilder data = newStringBuilder();JavaScriptSerializer json = newJavaScriptSerializer();                             json.Serialize(tasks, data);      hdData5.Value = data.ToString();

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `[Serializable()]` attribute on your custom class and then:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var Json = serializer.Serialize(myObject);
```

To ignore specific properties in the object you're serializing, simply place the `[NonSerialized]` attribure on them.

I Just Referred From [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307100/servicestack-text-how-to-serialize-class-to-json)